# Hyper-parameter optimization for regression to avoid overfiting/underfiting

Tags: regression, optimization, hyperparameter, smoothing

I am using Penalized spline to smooth noisy data. Those splines are non parametric regression models which only rely on a smoothing parameter $\lambda \geq 0$ (which has to be chosen).

I would like to find the "best" parameter that would describe well data without overfiting it or underfiting.

Let $(x_i,y_i)_{i\in[1,n]}$ be a set of points such that $x_1 < x_2 <\dots < x_n$ . Once $\lambda$ is chosen the corresponding penalized spline curve $f$ found minimizes
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - f(x_i))^2 + \lambda \int_{x_1}^{x_n} [f''(x)]^2 dx$

Basically $\lambda$ controls the trade-off between the goodness of fit and the smoothness of the fitted curve.

- if $\lambda= 0$, $f$ interpolate data hence it overfits
- if $\lambda\to +\infty$ the integral as too become smaller and smaller: $f$ obtained is a linear regression hence underfit data.

I would like to find a way to find the optimal value of $\lambda$ but I cannot use a $\chi^2$ tests otherwise the solution found would be $\lambda = 0$.

For example I obtain this for a value $\lambda = 1500$ (red is data and blue is p-spline)
[image]

I found a criterion called cross-validated residual sum of squares (CVRSS) to minimize and the minimum corresponds to the best value $\lambda$ (Method described in Annex B of the following document http://curis.ku.dk/ws/files/164301283/thesis_helene_rytgaard.pdf)
But it gives me a corresponding $f$ curve which overfit too much data in my case.

Many thanks in advance if you have a solution to propose to this problem

Comment: I'd recommend checking out a standard text like chapter 7 on model selection from Elements of Statistical Learning (available for free here https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) and refining what you're trying after you get a sense of what's out there. E.g. comparing k-fold cross validation to generalized cross validation and other things like that (making sure to keep a test set preserved for final assessments)

Comment: Dear @jld thanks I am going to read it and let you know. For precision I do not have extra measurement, I only have different measurement (by different I mean not similar) as shown in the image above so I cannot use "another" sample but I do not want for each curve to search by hand a good value of $\lambda$

Comment: ok, if you're trying to make predictions on new data you will want to consider training/test splits, but if you're just looking to describe the particular sampled data then that will be ok. Either way I think that chapter should give you some good places to start

Comment: How did you determine that the model selected by cross validation was overfit?

Comment: Dear @user20160, well I did not determined it but basically it was super close to the red curve (data) whereas I would like it to be like in the plot above.
I am searching for a criterion to minimize to grasp the general trend of the curve rather than the fluctuation